# Horário de verão com datas antigas

Tags: c#, .net, data

No meu sistema salvo todas as datas em **UTC**, porém na exibição para o usuário eu mostro em **GMT -3**.

O problema está quando eu salvo um data no horário de verão, pois no caso ela não será mais feito a diferença de 3 horas, ele salva fazendo a conversão de maneira correta, porém quando eu vou recuperar essa mesma data numa época que não seja no horário de verão ela irá me retornar com um valor diferente, já que quando ele salvou não era mais a diferença padrão de 3 horas e no momento da busca é.

Como posso resolver esse problema do horário de verão, utilizando **C#**.

Atualmente pára fazer as conversões eu utilizo `ToLocalTime()` e `ToUniversalTime()`.

Comment: Acho que você não vai ter como escapar de informar no banco de dados que determinada data foi salva no horário de verão, se não informar, não vai ter como saber, a não ser você crie regras de intervalo de datas, como 'todas as datas salvas em periodo 25/08/todos até 01/03/todos' foram salvas no horário de verão, e com essa regra identificar quando for exibir a data se ela foi salva nesse periodo, se sim desconta a hora, caso contrário apenas exibe

Comment: Um negócio que não faz sentido nenhum é quando voce cita: "O problema é quando eu salvo a data em horário de verão".. vamos analisar: Imagina que são 15:00.. em UTC seria 18:00, certo? no horário de verão seria 16:00 e UTC 18:00, o horário UTC nunca muda.. o que muda é o horario que é convertido.

Comment: Jefferson aí voce precisa por um condicional, quando a data estiver dentro do horário de verão (data consultada) voce calcula +2, senão +3... a função na minha resposta faz exatamente isso, imagine que você busca um período de 01 ano, e no meio desse ano o horário mudou certo? de Junho-2016 à Junho-2017.. sendo assim no meio da consulta, usando função ou o loop que voce preferir usar você terá que validar e calcular de forma correta DENTRO DO RANGE do horário de verão..

Comment: Mas a questão é que ambas são 19:00, então está tudo certo. O que talvez você queira é usar o (local time* a segunda hipótese que eu falei em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/237072/hor%c3%a1rio-de-ver%c3%a3o-com-datas-antigas?noredirect=1#comment485421_237072. Normalmente isto é um erro, mas se for o que quer dá também, só que não pode gravar mais em UTC. Você pode gravar até ambos, ou alguma informação que uma calcule a outra. Depende da sua necessidade. Como eu imaginei desde o princípio a necessidade não está clara.

Comment: @bigown É isso mesmo que preciso, preciso a data no localtime, porém como as datas estão gravadas em UTC isso, causa alguns problemas quando junta o horário de verão. Então a solução seria grava fora do UTC ou então como um string? Ou o ToLocalTime(), quando eu utilizo ele ele verifica se naquele período era horário de verão ou não para exibi a data no horário local.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Caso você tenha certeza em qual zona o horário foi criado, você pode usar este método:

```
public static DateTime ConvertToBrazilianTime(DateTime utc)
{
    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId
        (utc, "E. South America Standard Time"); // Horário de Brasilia/BRA
}
```

Este método recebe uma data UTC e converte ela para a zona especificada, ele é *inteligente* o suficiente para identificar se o horário de verão estava vigente no local e data especificados.

**Exemplo:**

```
// Data UTC 15/12/2012 10:00:00
DateTime dataUtc = MinhaQueryDoBanco.DataUtc;

// Converte de UTC para horário de Brasilia
// O método sabe que nessa data (15/12/2012) o horário de verão estava vigente
// então o datetime é convertido para 15/12/2012 08:00:00
// usando -02:00 ao invés de -03:00
DateTime dataLocal = ConvertToBrazilianTime(dataUtc);
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fdhFBE)

**Exemplo 2**:

```
var date = new List<DateTime>();

// Criando Lista com range de datas.
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    date.Add(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-i));
}

foreach (var d in date)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ConvertToBrazilianTime(d));
}
```

**Resultado (observe a diferença no dia 16 quando o horário de verão entra em vigência):**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EuiDx0)

Comment: O Problema são as datas armazenadas... logo ele tem que saber qual foi o período do horário de verão para então converter

Comment: Alex eu adicionei algumas informações e o resultado. Desconhecia esse método que postou, obrigado!

Comment: Se minha data for gravada no horário de verão e eu pesquisar fora do horário de verão, vai mostrar a data correta no horário que foi gravado?

Comment: @JefersonAlmeida Sim, desde que você tenha certeza que a data foi gravada na zona especificada no método, que no caso do meu exemplo é o horário de Brasilia. Ele vai pegar a data UTC e converter para o horário de Brasilia e analisar se naquela data o horário de verão estava em vigor. Se a data veio de Hong Kong, temos um problema...

Comment: @downvoter Se importa(m) de comentar os votos negativos? Apenas votar negativamente e não comentar o porque não ajuda muito a comunidade.

Answer (score 5):

Está havendo confusão na pergunta e comentários.

Um horário como dizemos informalmente é um ponto no tempo. Ele existe de forma única. Tempo é algo astrofísico, não tem fuso. Por isto o correto é sempre tratar pontos no tempo como UTC que é um horário universal.

Este site faz isto. E é o correto. Em geral sites tem problemas de apresentação porque eles não consideram o fuso na máquina do usuário. Nenhum grande problema, o horário está certo a apresentação não, por isto este site optou por não tentar adivinhar o fuso e usa UTC como apresentação. Eu sei que muita gente acha absurdo, mas isto tem lá suas vantagens, além das desvantagens.

Em uma aplicação para usuário mais leigo o ideal é apresentar o horário dentro do fuso. Apresentação é algo diferente do horário em si. Apresentação é algo visual, é eventual.

Se o interesse é o ponto no tempo não importa muito como entrou o horário ou como vai apresentar, apenas o horário universal interessa. Então se alguém entrar com 22:00 em GMT-0200 ou 21:00 em GMT-0300 ou 18:00 em GMT-0600, e aí não faz diferença se isto é horário de verão ou não, é fuso, tudo sera 00:00UTC.

Se a máquina do usuário estiver com fuso errado é problema daquela máquina. O máximo que pode-se fazer é o sistema não confiar no sistema operacional e pedir para o usuário informar qual é o fuso dele. O que também é inconfiável, se bobear até mais. Usuário faz confusão.

Se algo estiver configurado errado na ma´quina é problema dele. É possível criar alternativas próprias para tentar ajudar.

Agora, se você não deseja um ponto no tempo aí precisa gravar o horário de outra forma. Se o que deseja é o **horário visual** do momento que o evento ocorreu aí grave este horário e não um ponto no tempo.

Uma forma de fazer isto é gravar o horário como *local time* mesmo. Você sabe que aquele campo é uma representação visual do horário e não o horário em si.

Também pode continuar gravando UTC e ter um outro campo que diga qual é o uso usado, assim na hora de apresentar sabe calcular o horário de apresentação.

Como isto não é um ponto no tempo, não é uma quantificação pode até mesmo gravar uma *string* com o horário, é só uma descrição.

Se você tem horário antigos em UTC e quer saber qual é o fuso deles sem ter isto gravado, sinto muito, não tem o que fazer, erro de legado que será carregado pro resto da vida. É como você usar um inteiro e um dia decidir que queria as casas decimais do número gravado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado, isso mesmo que queria saber, o que provavelmente terei que fazer é salvar as datas como localtime e não mais UTC, já que o horário visual é de extrema importância para o processo do usuário.