# Se eu tenho dois servidores (aplicação e banco de dados) com fusos horários diferentes, qual é melhor para utilizar como base?

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, .net, datetime

Estou trabalhando com o servidor MySQL de uma hospedagem, não consigo alterar o fuso horário do mesmo, ou seja ele utiliza o "Mountain Standard time (MST)", já por outro lado, estou utilizando o servidor ASP.NET e nele consigo setar o fuso horário para o horário de "Horario de Brasilia (BRST)", a diferença é que o MST tem -5 horas e sempre que vou comparar algo utilizando o `DateTime.Now` no ASP.NET eu tenho problemas.

Qual é o mais usual para se trabalhar como padrão?

Comment: Talvez esse artigo da Microsoft possa te ajudar a contornar o problema https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/datetime/converting-between-time-zones

Comment: Defina um padrão e use-o sempre, independentemente do que o servidor usa.

Comment: me parece que você tem um problema de projeto, não somente implementação, você rotinas que pegam o horário no banco no lugar de passar da camada de aplicação? é isso?

Comment: Eu tenho o seguinte: Preciso comparar intervalos de tempo para permitir ou não um usuário fazer download. Quando uso o `NOW()` do MYSQL, ele me retorna digamos que 00:00:00, quando utilizo o `DateTime.Now` do C# , eu recebo 05:00:00.

Comment: Gostaria de saber qual padrão adotar

Comment: Tempo universal UTC, é usado como base para todos horários

Comment: Teoricamente o servidor deve responder o seu horário local, se o seu mysql é uma parte interna, então isso não tem muita importância para o usuário, para questões internas a saída é converter para UTC (tempo universal) e comparar os horários, mas como você já sabe de antemão que são 5 horas de diferença é só somar (ou subtrair se for o caso) 5 horas antes de comparar... Alguns agentes checam a sincronia de relógio entre si, portanto é importante fornecer a hora correta ao usuário, num caso mais genérico...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Horários deveriam ser sempre armazenados e manipulados como UTC, feito isso nenhum problema ocorrerá (ou quase, não é tão simples, mas para maioria dos cenários é ok). Você só trata de horário local na entrada e saída de dados, sempre fazendo a entrada se converter para UTC e o UTC ser convertido para o horário local desejado naquele contexto.

Não importa qual é a sua infraestrutura essa é a única forma correta, a não ser que precise de um marcador fixo de horário, onde a hora em si (um ponto na linha do tempo) não importa, mas sim o que estava mostrando em um relógio específico ou é um indicador abstrato de horário, o que talvez até deveria ser apenas um texto.

Formas erradas só devem ser usadas quando há legado de dados que exija isso e não pode ser conformado em novo padrão (tem vários locais de horário, mas não se sabe qual é o de cada hora, ou código que lida de forma errada. Ambos serão pesadelos.

Se for o caso, [em dados não tem muito o que fazer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/237095/101) sem assumir coisas erradas, se for código a solução depende de cada problema.